# Setting Default Send-From Address on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sharing

If I take a photo using the camera app, and then want to share it by email, the default is to send from my icloud email address. I have my gmail set up on my phone using exchange, and that had always been the default until recently (with all that icloud stuff).

How can I set my gmail address as the default send-from address when sharing a photo?

Answer (score 1):

For setting your default email account on an iOS device do the following:

Go to:

Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendar -> and scroll down to **Default account**.
(Hope I translated it correctly, but I guess it is clear what I mean)

Set the default account to your likings.

Comment: I actually already had this as the default account, and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to Settings -> iCloud and then turn off mail.