# Setting Default gmail Send-From Address on iPhone for photo sharing

Tags: iphone, email, gmail

If I take a photo using the camera and then to share it by email, the default is to send from one of my gmail addresses configured.  I'm trying to use the one of the other gmail address as the From address.

This question is similar:
[Setting Default Send-From Address on iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72394/setting-default-send-from-address-on-iphone)

But that question along with the rest of what I can find on the web, only deal with a single gmail email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving an IOS update to 10.1.1, I was then asked which email address to use when sending a photo.  Either I didn't find the right spot under IOS 9 or this was addressed in IOS 10.